# Prebuilt native library in android application

Tags: android, eclipse, osmdroid, android-native-library

I have an android application which uses some prebuilt native libraries ([Osmand prebuilt libraries](http://download.osmand.net/resource/jni-prebuilt.zip)). The problem is that when I run the application on mobile phone, it says that these libraries are missing. 
When I looked in the .apk file, there is no "lib" folder - how to set up eclipse to export them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution. It's easier then I expected. All I need is to place the libraries into the libs folder.

```
libs
  \---armeabi
  \---armeabi-v7a
  \---mips
  \---x86
```

Eclipse creates the lib folder in apk by itself.

Comment: Do you mean to run an apk on x86 emulation I have to create `libs-x86` folder inside `libs` ? If not then what ?

Comment: @prateek : you must create a subfolder named x86 in the directory libs

Comment: To get the native libraries in the apk, you must also add the native library location in proj props (workspace/libs in this case) as well as adding it to the exports

Comment: i use android studio , i copy external library like picasso on x86 folder but it`s not work .