# Install app on genymotion device ,meet:“INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE”

Tags: android, simulator, genymotion

When I install my app on a genymotion simulater device,it can not be installed well,on console I got "INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE"
I trid another app,it installed fine.I do not know why.

Comment: Does your application have any native code (are you using C/C++ and the JNI) or are you only using Java?

Comment: @FuegoFro  No,I didn't...

Comment: any suggestion to solve it for Eclipse editor?

Comment: I followed this and it worked for me:http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The application (certainly a game) must be ARM only.
Genymotion is a x86 platform, so compile the application to target x86.

You may be able to install ARM support manually : 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952

Comment: Thank you @slvn,I don't know how to compile the app to target x86 but  I followed the instruction of your url to installed ARM support manually ,it worked.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using IntelliJ it may be related to the project's default configuration.  IntelliJ will assume, unless otherwise specified, that Native libraries will be stored in the `Libs` folder. This is usually where developer store their `JAR` libraries.  IntelliJ build process will package up the `JAR` file into the Native file folder in the APK.

If you experiencing this problem, you can find a good **How-to**:

[**INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE Intellj**](http://blog.iteedee.com/2014/02/android-install_failed_cpu_abi_incompatible-intellj/)

This helped to resolve the issue I had.

Comment: This works for me. The reason is that IntelliJ copies "google-play-services.jar.properties" from google play services to "lib" folder inside the apk. The installer seems to think that "google-play-services.jar.properties" is a CPU architecture name.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out my answer here:

[INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE on device using intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20185696/3000133)

I know it's written for IntelliJ, but you could be running into a similar issue with Eclipse where it thinks that some normal Java files or jar libraries are native code and including it in the compiled APK. A quick way to find out is to open up the final APK (it's just a jar file, so most utilities should be able to decompress it) and make sure that the only things you see are `META-INF`, `res`, `AndroidManifest.xml`, `classes.dex`, and `resources.arsc`. It's possible that there are other valid files in a normal Java Android application, but in general if you see anything else in there, particularly a `libs` folder, it's probably the result of the compilation process thinking that those other things are native libraries (compiled C/C++ code using the JNI).

If this is the case, you'll need to configure Eclipse to not interpret the Java libraries you're using as native code. Now, I don't personally use Eclipse so I don't know where the proper settings would be, but based off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591645/prebuilt-native-library-in-android-application) answer, it looks like Eclipse automatically assumes that the `libs` folder in the root of your project contains native libraries. The easiest solution may be to move any Java libraries you are using into a different folder (such as `libraries`).

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.iteedee.com/2014/02/android-install_failed_cpu_abi_incompatible-intellj/
The INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE error is generated when you attempt to install an android application on a device with an unsupported CPU architecture. This error is usually related to the native libraries that are not packaged up for the device’s CPU architecture (ie: x86, ARMv6, ARMv7, etc).

Now, if you have an application that doesn’t use any native libraries or *.so file you might be scratching your head on this one. If you use IntelliJ IDEA IDE for your android development it might be packaging all of your related .JAR file in to the Native Library file location in your APK.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the same problem was different in my case.

I had added some dependency jars in `/libs` directory of my Android app project. One of these jars had exported library in jar format; i.e. a jar within a jar file. I've noticed that the apk created using jars with such structure are incompatible with x86 based devices (don't know why).