# Running libgdx game on genymotion?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, genymotion

Hi i'm trying to test my libgdx on ganymotion but i keep getting this error:

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE
```

The emulator device is Galaxy Nexus - 4.3 - API 18 - 720x1280 and i am on Windows 7.

The only logcat errors is:

```
12-30 06:51:24.373: E/cutils-trace(1279): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

logcat warnings are:

```
12-30 06:51:24.421: W/ActivityManager(438): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/Connect4-android.apk
12-30 06:51:24.425: W/ActivityManager(438): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/Connect4-android.apk
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install app on genymotion device ,meet:“INSTALL\_FAILED\_CPU\_ABI\_INCOMPATIBLE”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416216/install-app-on-genymotion-device-meet-install-failed-cpu-abi-incompatible)

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution to the problem. In their last update genymotion they removed the ARM translation, which causes the INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE. [Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952) you can download the ARM translation, install it in genymotion and the problem should be fixed.