# Android Studio : com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, arcgis

I'm trying to use ArcGis with Android Studio.  I tried to follow these steps

- https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/install-and-set-up.htm
- http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/05/20/using-the-arcgis-android-sdk-with-android-studio-part-1/

but I face this error :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

My app structure

[image]

app : build.gradle

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        // Add the following arcgis repository
        maven {
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/esri/arcgis'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is your parent build.gradle. Can you also include the one in app/build.gradle?

Comment: you can check the image in the post + the listed build.gradle

Comment: If you take out the ArcGIS dependency and related code, does it work?

Comment: After taking the dependency out the app compiled but not run , check this error                                                                                                         DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.testarcgis"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.testarcgis
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE]

Comment: Thanks @ Daniel A. González , it's working now on Device , the above exception throws when running the app on genymotion.

Comment: Can you support me how to fix this issue on genymotion ?

Comment: I am not sure, you might want to create a new question for that. However, CPU ABI incompatible means that you are trying to use, for example, an x86 app in a arm emulator, so make sure they match. Not sure how you would do so though.

Comment: A quick Google search gave me this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27700397/2245921 Basically I assume you added some libraries (JARs or .so native C libraries) that are not compiled for all the architectures that you are trying to support. Refer to that question for more details.

Comment: No problem! If your question is answered, please mark my answer as the correct one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like my comments above answered the question.