# Android Studio : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How Can I solve this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

App Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"


packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1' // Do NOT use 22.2.0 even it is newer one. It reported to cause some problems with other dependencies.
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+')
        {
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
        }
compile group:'com.octo.android.robospice', name:'robospice-spring-android', version:'1.4.7'

compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-spring-android:1.4.7'

compile group:'org.codehaus.jackson', name:'jackson-mapper-asl', version:'1.9.11'

compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.2'

compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.2'

compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.2'

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'

compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-ormlite:1.4.6'

compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
//        exclude module: 'xpp3'
//        exclude group: 'stax'
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
}

}
```

Project gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

Android Mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app" >

<!-- Permission - Internet Connect -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<!-- Permission - Location - GPS Service -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Network State Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Call Phone Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<application
    android:name=".app.AppHelper"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <service
        android:name="com.octo.android.robospice.Jackson2SpringAndroidSpiceService"
        android:exported="false" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCU__5jhNC-QaU9tXNpr7ikPio3km1UYe8" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.splash.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.base.BaseDrawerFragmentActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale"
        android:label=""
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    </activity>

</application>
```

Libs Folder
No Libs Folder Exist Now

Comment: you have asked this question before (rather than duplicating questions you should put a bounty on the original question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518323/android-studio-com-android-ide-common-process-processexception

Comment: perhaps you should update your build tools? 21.1.2 is old, there is a 22.0.1 now

Comment: @ Quintin Balsdon it's the same error but with another app with another structure, so i posted it as another question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome. You are at the first step of Android gradle hell.

1. Update your Android SDK components in SDK Manager to latest one including Extra > Google Repository (recommend to add almost all in Extra).
2. Let's wash up your current file.

   - **AndroidManifest.xml**: Remove the `<uses-sdk ... />` lines. It's redundant as gradle file already defines it.
   - **Build.gradle**: Comment all `compile files('libs/xxxxxxx.jar')` lines. The first line `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` will include all jar files in `libs` folder. And, use `compile` from maven repository not jar files in order to maintain your dependencies fresh.

For example, SimpleXML has repository id as below. Place the code below of the `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` line and remove 'simple-xml-2.7.1.jar' file in libs folder.

```
compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
}
```

Likewise, find repository id of each jar file in your libs folder and replace it below of the `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` line one by one. Make only jar files which unable to find in maven repository remain in libs folder.

Finally, remove `proguardFiles` line. You need to find and fix the problem in general condition, then apply progruard afterward.

3. Set version of buildToolsVersion and compileSdkVersion to latest one.

My recommendation of today is as below,
(numbers may vary when someone will see this post in the future)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled = false
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    ...
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1' // Do NOT use 22.2.0 even it is newer one. It reported to cause some problems with other dependencies.
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.+')
        {
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
        }
}
```

4. command `gradle assembleDebug` again. (for Windows, `gradlew assembleDebug`)
5. If failed again, try to find and fix dependencies version conflict issues one by one. You may see `exclude module: ...` in my code. These resolve the conflict issue. Detailed instruction is given at the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30649660/361100

Comment: Youngjae check my updated gradle , removed all libs , but the same error still happen.

Comment: @ahmedShoeib // remove `proguardFiles` line first. And, did you proceed No. 5 that I recommended? If it is, I recommend you to execute `gradle assembleDebug --stacktrace` and find the problem exactly. You can post failure result of `--stacktrace` or `--info` option.

Comment: the result for command ./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile : check this url https://gist.github.com/ahmedshoeib/f433839f392e7a650eaa

Comment: check the updated gradle and command output here https://gist.github.com/ahmedshoeib/27b0ec30309f787b30f9

Comment: @ahmedShoeib // I recommend you to execute gradle with `--debug` (not `--info` sorry above my wrong comment) or `--stacktrace` option. It will show you error causes.

Comment: check the result for ./gradlew --debug : https://gist.github.com/ahmedshoeib/64970f813b1a79f1479f

Comment: @ahmedShoeib // hey. you got `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` in log. try Build > Clean Project and Rebuild. run `gradlew assembleDebug --debug`. If failed, `gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace` is better option to diagnose.

Comment: and for command : ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace  check this https://gist.github.com/ahmedshoeib/b8001d36a5b7db602fad

Comment: @ahmedShoeib // You got conflict of support-v4 library. I read your dependencies log and found that you had bad guy `com.google.android:support-v4:r7`. exclude it. I also edit gradle a little for future build error you may got.

Comment: exlude it from where ?

Comment: @ahmedShoeib // from `org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2` or its mother dependencies `com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-spring-android`

Comment: Thanks alot Youngjae for your support i solved it by removing com.google.android:support-v4:r7 from spring-android and from : compile group:'com.octo.android.robospice', name:'robospice-spring-android', version:'1.4.7'

Comment: @ahmedShoeib // glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried commenting out the following in your build.gradle:

```
//compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

REFERENCE: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=161605

Comment: yes  i found this page before and tested what will do if i commented this line but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly this one worked for me

```
defaultConfig {
multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Source: 
[Android Studio fails to debug with error org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640314/android-studio-fails-to-debug-with-error-org-gradle-process-internal-execexcepti)

Answer (score 0):

The same error occurred to me when I imported all the Google Play Services APIs, as you do with

`compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+')`

Try removing this line and import only the Services APIs that you need: [Google Play Services Setup](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)