# Android Studio - UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, android-studio, adt

I am getting the following error when I am trying to add the NordicSemi DFU library to app. Previously it was running but now it is throwing this error

```
    Error:15:49:43.892 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/print/PrintHelperKitkat$2$1;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:685)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/print/PrintHelper$PrintHelperKitkatImpl;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:685)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"2 errors; aborting","sources":[{}]}

15:49:43.905 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
15:49:43.906 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
15:49:43.906 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
15:49:43.906 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
15:49:43.907 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
15:49:43.907 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
15:49:43.907 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
15:49:43.908 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
15:49:43.909 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
15:49:43.909 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
15:49:43.910 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
15:49:43.910 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
15:49:43.910 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
15:49:43.911 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
15:49:43.911 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
15:49:43.911 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
15:49:43.912 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
15:49:43.912 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
15:49:43.912 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
15:49:43.912 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
15:49:43.913 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
15:49:43.913 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
15:49:43.913 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
15:49:43.914 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
15:49:43.914 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
15:49:43.914 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
15:49:43.914 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
15:49:43.915 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
15:49:43.915 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
15:49:43.915 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
15:49:43.915 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
15:49:43.916 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
15:49:43.916 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
15:49:43.916 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
15:49:43.917 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
15:49:43.917 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:43)
15:49:43.917 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
15:49:43.917 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
15:49:43.918 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
15:49:43.918 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
15:49:43.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
15:49:43.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
15:49:43.919 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
15:49:43.920 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
15:49:43.921 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
15:49:43.921 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
15:49:43.922 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
15:49:43.922 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
15:49:43.923 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
15:49:43.923 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
15:49:43.923 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
15:49:43.924 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
15:49:43.924 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
15:49:43.924 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
15:49:43.925 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
15:49:43.925 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
15:49:43.926 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
15:49:43.926 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
15:49:43.926 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
15:49:43.927 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
15:49:43.927 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
15:49:43.928 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
15:49:43.928 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
15:49:43.928 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
15:49:43.929 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
15:49:43.929 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
15:49:43.930 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:39)
15:49:43.930 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:66)
15:49:43.930 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:235)
15:49:43.930 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
15:49:43.931 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:222)
15:49:43.931 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
15:49:43.931 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
15:49:43.932 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
15:49:43.932 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 55 more
15:49:43.932 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
15:49:43.932 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:42)
15:49:43.933 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCode(AndroidBuilder.java:1276)
15:49:43.933 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$convertByteCode$2.call(Unknown Source)
15:49:43.933 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.doTaskAction(Dex.groovy:165)
15:49:43.934 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.this$6$doTaskAction(Dex.groovy)
15:49:43.934 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex$this$6$doTaskAction.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
15:49:43.934 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.taskAction(Dex.groovy:99)
15:49:43.934 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
15:49:43.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 61 more
15:49:43.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
15:49:43.935 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
15:49:43.936 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:40)
15:49:43.936 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 68 more
15:49:43.936 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

Don't know how to resolve this one, I tried number of ways but no luck.
Here is my .gradle file

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

ext.multiarch=false

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':CordovaLib')
    compile project(':GATT-IP-LIB')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    //    compile 'no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18:scanner:0.1.1'
    compile project(':dfu')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 20151016
        versionName '0.0.1'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.12'
}

def getProjectList() {
    def manifestFile = file("project.properties")
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("android.library.reference.(\\d+)\\s*=\\s*(.*)")
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestFile.getText())
    def projects = []
    while (matcher.find()) {
      projects.add(":" + matcher.group(2).replace("/",":"))
    }
    return projects
}
```

Please help me out....

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Android Studio : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819702/android-studio-unexpected-top-level-exception)*. Both **app** and **:dfu** projects seem to depend on the support library. One should *exclude* it.

Comment: I think yes, I removed "compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')" from my gradle & added individual compiles to the jar's which I needed. Then it is working